# Running single jenkins job parallelly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Is there any way to run a single jenkins job parallelly without going to a queue. Currently I have a jenkins job which might be triggering from bitbucket in accordance with each pull request, currently all build triggers are going to a queue and pull request taking so much time. I have multiple executes configured but it always going for a queue. Please note that this build is completely happening in docker container in separate container instance.

Comment: if multiple instance of same job run parallel then system may become inconsistent right?

Comment: It's a docker based maven build and all builds are happening in seperate docker container so inconsistency will not come to the picture.

Comment: I got one option to solve this.. Created pipeline job so it can be triggers parellaly. Thank you for all help